# Rendering fields manually---Django

Tags: python, django-forms

I am learning to program in django and I have a question, I have been reading the django documentation on how to manually render the form fields, and I have not been able to understand and save the data; when I use form.as_p I can get the data to be saved to my database, but when I try to render it manually or separately I can't. Could someone please explain, then I leave the code I am using

**models.py**

```
class CrearUsuario(CreateView):
    model = Proveedor
    form_class = ProveedorForm
    template_name = 'contratacion/formsuser.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('proveedor')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProveedorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Proveedor
        fields = '__all__'
```

**forms.user.html**

```
<form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Razon Social</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{form.razon_social}}
                    </div> 
                </div>   
        </div>       
        <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Sigla</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{form.sigla}}
                    </div> 
                </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```